# Invoking listselectionlistener of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

After successfully adding a `ListSelectionListener` and having it register user action, I now need to have a row preselected in the `JTable` view during when the `JFrame` containing it is initialized from a different class:

```
// in constructor
rowSM_treatments = table_histories.getSelectionModel();
rowSM_treatments.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
      if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;
               ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
               if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                   System.out.println("No rows are selected.");
               } else {
                   selectedRow_treatments = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
                   System.out.println("selected Row> " + selectedRow_treatments);
                   //do more
               }}});
// later on is this method which I mean to call from outside this class
  public void setSelectedRow(int row){
   rowSM_treatments.setLeadSelectionIndex(row);       
     }
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what is going wrong, and also forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than play with the selection model directly I usually just access the table:

```
table.changeSelection(row, 0, false, false);
```

So as long as your other class has a refernce to the table you can do this.